# C# get specific database using GetScheme

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am trying to figure out how I can only list specific databases in my combo box for databases.  I have several database that all contain  _Logging.  I just want the logging ones to show up in the combo box.  How do I accomplish this?  After the getScheme is called, do I need to call another query to do something like '%Logging%' query or something like that?

```
 var databases = sqlConnection1.GetSchema("Databases");

            foreach (DataRow database1 in databases.Rows)
            {

                String dbName = database1.Field<String>("database_name");

                Console.WriteLine(dbName);

                cmbDatabaseList.Items.Add(dbName);

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you just do:

```
if (dbName.Contains("Logging"))
cmbDatabaseList.Items.Add(dbName);
```